# YII framework: CHTML.php not including

Tags: php

My site was working all fine on localhost but since when i have uploaded. It is showing an error

```
include(CHTML.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]:
```

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I am searching it since long and did many things for it.. 
Like importing `'system.web.helpers.*'` in `main.php`,Still its not working.

Please somebody help and do help in detail, am new to `YII`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Is your local machine Windows and your remote server a *nix box?  In that case, check your capitalization.  `CHTML.php` suggests that you have case-mismatches, try using `CHtml` in your code instead.

Comment: Great!  I ran into the same thing, but now I've swapped to working on OSX to catch this sort of thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Dev in Windows, deploy into Unix: Case sensitive issue.